# How can i install modules using ansible in linux

Tags: linux, ansible

i am just leaning `ansible` and so far i was able to ping the servers.

My main aim now is to install following modules like `apache , git` and if its already installed then should should not do anything.

I am not able to find how can i start with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [packaging modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_packaging_modules.html). For example:

```
# Install the package "foo"
- apt: pkg=foo state=present
```

As to "if its already installed", all ansible packages are idempotent and (whenever possible) do not re-do work that is already done.

Comment: i tried that and i get this error `apt is not a legal parameter in an Ansible Playbook
`

Comment: You must provide a code snippet if you want help with an error message. Since you are having "day one, and I obviously didn't even read the documentation table of contents" problems, maybe IRC is a better place to get hand-holding.